# Lost connection to device while clicking "Use Photo" on camera iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-camera

I'm using webview inside our application to show one website.  In the web one button(Take photo) will be there, on click of **Take photo** button it will open the camera.  Camera is taking pics correctly.  The problem is after taking photos its asking to "Use Photo", "Retake".

If I click **Use Photo** it is showing like connection lost. Eventhough device was connected properly its showing like this image. If I run the application without connecting to Xcode it is crashing. Where I'm doing wrong? Anyhelp could be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: did you get any  memory warning before connection lost?

Comment: Yes. In log its printing **ProductName[7869:744384] Received memory warning.**

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: Which code you want me to share? Loading webview code?

Comment: show your camera capturing session?

Comment: I'm not doing anything through code because its a webview.  I have added keys in plist file to get access for camera usage that's it.

Answer (score 0):

We miss the root cause of the crash. To get it, you should inspect all crash logs on your test device.

Run and make your application crash several times (take note of the exact hour of crash to reliable link each crash with its log), then connect your device to Xcode and go to `Window` | `Devices`, click your phone name then `View Device Logs`. You should find the crash logs of your application and/or some daemon.

Then you should check if you can understand the cause with those logs.